# Using MID,Find, IF

Tags: excel, if-statement, find

domain@dcsad, domain@ddcsf, domain1@dcsr, domain@dcsw, domain@ddcsf, domain@dcswb

that is what i have and want to extract the information after the "@" sign in all of them and return the values with separated with the "," between the values in a single cell if possible?

please Help!

Comment: Yup, and you seem to already know what functions to use. Any attempts?

Comment: =MID(IF(F3,FIND("@">",",F3)+1,5))

Comment: i am actually stuck in the middle of how i finish off the IF statement. or should i begin with the IF statement the follow with the MID and FIND

Comment: Erm, you are misusing FIND. It's `FIND([from text], [text to find])`. Start with MID, and then use FIND inside it. IF is not really needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cell **A1** contains the text string:

domain@dcsad, domain@ddcsf, domain1@dcsr, domain@dcsw, domain@ddcsf, domain@dcswb

then the simple User Defined Function:

```
Public Function Domains(st As String) As String
    ary1 = Split(st, ",")
    Domains = ""
    For i = LBound(ary1) To UBound(ary1)
        v = Split(ary1(i), "@")
        If Domains = "" Then
            Domains = v(1)
        Else
            Domains = Domains & "," & v(1)
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

will return:

dcsad,ddcsf,dcsr,dcsw,ddcsf,dcswb

to a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to apply Text To Columns with `@` and `,` as delimiters, delete every second column and stitch the results back together with concatenation, say something like:

```
=G3&", "&H3&", "&I3&", "&J3&", "&K3&", "&L3
```